# Symfony downgrade from 3.2 to 2.8 lts

Tags: php, symfony, structure, directory

I have started with symfony **3.2** project, then changed version in `composer` to **2.8** (which is long term support).

Problem is that folders structure still remains **3.2** project. Is there any way to change (not manually) folders structure to **2.8**?

Comment: why would you want to do something like this in the first place? Anyways it's probably easier to make a clean install for 2.8 and port the created code

Comment: 2.8 is lts version. Project is already in development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can downgrade. You might choose the old Symfony2 directory structure (deprecated) or keeping the current Symfony3 structure.
In either ways, please take a look at [How to Override Symfony's Directory Structure](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/override_dir_structure.html).

### Using the Symfony3 directory structure

If you choose to use the Symfony3 structure, it's easy as following up this article [about upgrading from Symfony2 to Symfony3's directory structure](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony3-upgrade/new-dir-structure).

### Using the Symfony2 directory structure

First you'll have to rename and move some files (like `var/cache/`, `var/logs/`, etc.). Afterwards you'll have to change the autoloading file in `app/autoload.php` (formerly `var/autoload.php` which you must move too).
Basically it's the same in reverse order like upgrading from Symfony2 to Symfony3 (mentioned above).

---

Please be aware that Symfony 3.4 (next LTS) will be released in November 2017, so in my opinion it's not worth to downgrade, and then re-upgrade. Upgrading from 3.2 to 3.4 will be small and fast, Upgrading from 2.8 to 3.4 could be much more to do ...